# Dart 2 and AngularDart 5 App Deployment and Run on Server Side

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Environment:

- Dart 2.0.0-dev.53.0
- AngularDart 2.0.0-alpha+10

I would like to know what is necessary to deploy and run an AngularDart App on server side in a VM.

Durring development is being used the `pub run build_runner server`. The application is accessed via `localhost:8080` on browser and it works fine.

To prepare to deployment a build is generated using the command `pub run build_runner build -r -o build`. The files are being generated on `build` directory ok.

The Google Cloud Compute is being used to create a VM.

Here are the basic doubts:

1. Dart has a specific Web Server or it's needs to install/use a tradicional Web
   Server like Apache (or which other better)?
2. It's necessary Dart VM or SDK on server side?
3. To deploy the build is just copy the `build` package generated into Web Server on server side? No needs additional configuration?
4. Anything more is necessary to do on server side to run the App?

Comment: 3 should do with any web server. There is no Dart involved in deployed Web apps, all is compiled to JS already in `build/`.

Comment: I am going to Apache then! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Dart has a specific Web Server or it's needs to install/use a traditional Web Server like Apache (or which other better)?

A Dart web app should run on any server that can run static content. We deploy samples to GitHub pages all of the time. See https://dart-lang.github.io/sample-pop_pop_win/

2) It's necessary Dart VM or SDK on server side?

Nope!

3) To deploy the build is just copy the build package generated into Web Server on server side? No needs additional configuration?

I would run `pub run build_runner build -r -o web:build` assuming your app is in the web directory. This will make sure to include the `packages` directory without symlinks. It will also build less!

4) Anything more is necessary to do on server side to run the App?

Nope!

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Should we also copy `packages` directory to the Web Server ? It is quite large ~42mb...